# QT Mediaplayer not mp3 playing

Tags: c++, qt, qmediaplayer

I am using Qt Creator version 3.5 and running Mediaplayer with Qtmediaplayer library but no error message in my code (C++), on Orangepi lite the qt software is working but Mp3 is not playing but on other operating systems the same program works fine.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I installed all the gstreamer libraries and it worked. Previously I only installed the ones for mp3, it didn't work.